# Multiple function calls while printing in python

Tags: python

I have some trouble understanding the output of this code.

```
def func(a,L = []):
    L.append(a)
    return(L)
print(func(1),func(3))
```

The output is [1,3][1,3]
It seems that each time it takes all the arguments from all the function calls each time a function is called. Does it happen due to same function being called in the same line? How does it work?

Comment: This has to be Python's most infamous gotcha xD - answer is in the dup.

Comment: In this case it occurs since they are all in the same line.  If you had `print(fun(1)); print(fun(2))` the output would be [1] and [1, 3].  When print evaluates its arguments its is left with print(L, L)-since fund returns L.  Since the last state of L is [1, 3], [1, 3] is printed twice.  See [Least Astonishment and Mutable Default Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument) for why the default argument keeps getting updated.

Comment: Thanks a lot @brunodesthuilliers and DarrylG . I get it now. Much appreciated.